# Android app, open connection to to mobile devices

Tags: android, sockets, websocket

what is the best way to create a two way constant communication between a server and an android app?

When I say constant communication, I mean client asking server for data or server constantly pushing data to clients.

From what I saw, I can't use websockets since they are designer for server/browser setups. Is that right? If so, what is the alternative?

Is there free frameworks to work with this in Android?

What I am trying to do is an application that works like a chatting but for multiple people. So they all will get in one "room or channel" on their devices, and then interact with each other, in a way handdled by the server.

Thanks!

Comment: Guys, sorry for the longest time in getting back on this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For continuously-open data connection, you may use [Sockets](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html). But you should also consider the fact that an always-open connection will drain your battery quickly too. For more details, read [this](http://android-er.blogspot.se/2011/01/simple-communication-using.html) and [this](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know , one possible way is using a web service where the client can connect to the server , if the web service is RESTFul there are many libraries to access it , one of them is the apache HTTPClient , for the server pushing the only way I know is C2DM for pushing data to clients.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at AutobahnAndroid:

https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid

which provides native Android/Java WebSocket client framework (plus WAMP = PubSub/RPC over WebSocket .. http://wamp.ws).

This is fully interoperable with WebSocket servers that server browser clients.

The AutobahnXX libraries (where XX = Python, JS, Android) are Open-Source (Apache 2.0). We (Tavendo) are offering a commercial virtual appliance based on Autobahn: http://autobahn.ws

Disclaimer: I am author of Autobahn and work for Tavendo.

Answer (score 0):

But keeping the connection running on the background on iOS and Android devices does drain the battery, for people who have this issue, I suggest using push notifications when the app is not on the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

> From what I saw, I can't use websockets since they are designer for
>   server/browser setups. Is that right? If so, what is the alternative?

Websocket is an IETF/W3C protocol, so it is not confined to a specific client platform. You can use Android websocket to get a two-way communication between Android and server side. For Android websocket client, I recommend using [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync). It has all websocket API that you need to establish the communication link and exchange data between Android and the server.